# Is there split brain possibility

Tags: database-administration

If there are 10 cameras recognizing number plates, and sending the data to the server with a backup server synchronized, is there a possibility to have split-brain problems when some things go wrong? Every piece of data has a timestamp, so if anything fails servers might renegotiate which data is correct, or am I wrong? I was preparing the installation when a colleague asked me about split-brain, and now I'm a little bit worried. And if it can happen, can I somehow remedy it without buying 3rd server?

Comment: You should at the very least mention which database you are using.

Comment: The problem is, I don't really know. Program getting number plates is splitting servers in standby mode,  the client wants to have the same equal copy on both servers, and I somehow have to manage that. Program is called "vdg" for cctv

Answer (score 1):

Split-brain is a situation, when a replica got any changes, that are not applied in master server. [Here is](https://www.continuent.com/resources/blog/what-earth-split-brain-scenario-mysql-database-cluster) a good explanation.

Fencing method helps to avoid split-brain situation. [Here are details](https://clusterlabs.github.io/PAF/fencing.html) about it.

If you dont want to have a deal with fencing, try to use quorum-oriented databases ([etcd](https://etcd.io/) for example). Such applications usually use [RAFT protocol](https://raft.github.io/) for lead election, and prevent data changes if they are not in quorum majority.